# Angular deferred promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a function that returns deferred promise in Angular.

I have used `$$state` to access its values from calling class but not sure if this is the right way.

Should I use `.then` instead or is there any standard way to access a specific variable for `$q.deferred` Promise object?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: The OP's question is quite clear and shouldn't need any code sample, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should **not** be accessing `$$state` directly.  Use a `.then` to define a callback that will have the data passed to it.

For example:

```
var promise = service.getDefferredPromise();

promise.then(function(data) {
   //use the data
   $scope.something = data.something;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I then access what's in `.then` and set it so it's available outside `.then` or should I wrap the entire rest of the function lines with `.then` (inside //use the data in your example)?

Comment: In angular, you would set the property that is bound.  Like `$scope.something = data` inside the `then`.  This works because `$q` knows about the angular digest cycle.   This works because of JS closure.  So, you can set any property that is inside the closure.